# what Is the true form for this "#${variable}"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't figure it out. Im trying to add type inside $("#") but can do this.Thanks For Helping me !

```
type = $(this).attr("id");
$("#${type}").html($(this).html());
```

Comment: Do you mean [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)? If so it only works with that specific backtick.

Comment: these 2 row in different function can't do $(this)

Comment: This only makes sense if you're using duplicate IDs - don't use duplicate IDs.

Comment: "*these 2 row in different function can't do $(this)*" - but you have 2 `$(this)` in the same code?  confusing.

Comment: i am trying to get another div by id like $("#id") but instead of id I am trying to write a variable like ${type}  when I try $("# ${type}") not working

Comment: Because you are using the wrong backticks. Check the first link or the linked duplicate.

Comment: Instead of `$("#${type}")` use `$(\`#${type}\`)`